# Overwrite an item if it already exists in Azure Cosmos DB while bulk importing from Java

Tags: java, json, azure, import, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using `Java DocumentDb bulk-executor` to bulk import an array of json to `Azure Cosmos DB`.

Sample `JSON` :

```
[
  {
    "SId": "101",
    "SName": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "SId": "102",
    "SName": "XYZ"
  }
]
```

Sample Code :

(PARTTION_KEY = "\SId")

```
DocumentCollection collection = Utilities.createEmptyCollectionIfNotExists(client, DATABASE, CONTAINER, PARTITION_KEY, THROUGHPUT);
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\samplejson.json");



                Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

                JSONArray jsonArray  = (JSONArray) obj;

                if (jsonArray  != null) {
                    int len = jsonArray.size();
                    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                        list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                    }
                }



                client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(30);
                client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(9);



                DocumentBulkExecutor.Builder bulkExecutorBuilder = DocumentBulkExecutor.builder().from(client, DATABASE, CONTAINER,
                collection.getPartitionKey(), 20000);

                DocumentBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = bulkExecutorBuilder.build();

                client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(0);
                client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(0);
                BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = bulkExecutor.importAll(list, false, false, null);
                System.out.println(bulkImportResponse.getNumberOfDocumentsImported());
```

Now if I have this another JSON :

```
[
  {
    "SId": "101,         // Item with this SID has already been inserted
    "SName": "ABCDEF"
  },
  {
    "SId": "103",
    "SName": "PQR"
  }
]
```

I want to insert this JSON to the same container. But it's just stored as a new entry and with a different "id", automatically created by Cosmos DB.

How can I bulk import and overwrite if item on the basis of"SId", if it already exists, at the same time?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the isUpsert flag in your call to importAll to be true.  This will enable the Upsert operation which means it will either add a new document if the id doesn't already exist, or it will update an existing document if the id is already there.

Change line:

```
BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = bulkExecutor.importAll(list, false, false, null);
```

To

```
BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = bulkExecutor.importAll(list, true, false, null);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java#bulk-import-data-to-azure-cosmos-db

Comment: No, it is still just making new entries. I tried the same.

Comment: It is only updating on "id". Although I've chosen "SId" as my partition key. Is it possible to do so on "SId"?

Comment: The ID needs to be unique within each partition, so if the ID and Sid both match an existing document then it should update.  If the ID matches but the Sid doesn't match then it's going to insert a new document.  I generally use Guids for ID to ensure uniqueness across partitions to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think you may be confusing ID and Partition Key.  The ID is a unique identifier for each document within a partition. This is what cosmos uses to determine if a document already exists.  The partition key is an element in your document used to group documents into different logical partitions.  Many documents can have the same partition key value, and it just means they are all stored in the same logical partition. [take a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview)

Comment: Thank you, this was really a very helpful solution and explanation @Paul.

Comment: Also, I have a doubt that does Azure cosmos, do the import in random order?